# Trying to get node.js app to work on cPanel

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, cpanel

I followed a tutorial on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2hhEOGXcCvg&t=11s&ab_channel=TheCodingTrain) that shows how to make a node.js server that works with sockets.
Here is the final working server.js code.

```js
    var express = require('express');

    var app = express()
    var server = app.listen(3000)

    app.use(express.static('public'))

    console.log('My sockets server is running.');

    var socket = require('socket.io')

    var io = socket(server)

    io.sockets.on('connection', newConnection)

    function newConnection(socket) {
        console.log('new connection: ', socket.id)
    
        socket.on('send-msg', data => {
            console.log('send-msg');
            socket.broadcast.emit('send-msg', data)
        })
    }
```

This code works when I host it on my local server (http://localhost:3000/). Now I am trying to get it to be online using cPanel, I got the libraries set up correctly (I think) and I am using the same code, but it's not working. I'm just getting `Cannot GET /mychat` poping up in the display.

I tried making some changes:

```js
    ...

    const hostname = '[the ip address of my server]';
    const port = 3000; // also tried port 22, same issue

    var app = express()
    var server = app.listen(port, hostname, () => {
        console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
    });

    ...
```

But I get the same issue.

When cPanel first created the server.js file, it made this code:

```js
    var http = require('http');
    var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        var message = 'It works!\n',
            version = 'NodeJS ' + process.versions.node + '\n',
            response = [message, version].join('\n');
        res.end(response);
    });
    server.listen();
```

which does it's job, but it doesn't help me.

Here is the basic structure of the site:

```
    root
      - package.json
      - package-lock.json
      - server.js
      > node_modules (folder with all of the required files including express and socket)
      > public
          - index.html
          - script.js
          - styles.css
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to define the path and the directory, so the server can receive and send an Httpresponce. For the main directory it would be:

```
app.get('/' (req, res) => {
     res.send('Home page') 
});
```

In this case the main directory is just '/' and the server gets a request, whenever a client goes to the url and then it responds, in this case with a text document, 'Home page'.

Comment: Where in my code am I putting this and what is `Home page`? I need it to point to `./public/index.html`

Comment: My JS is fine. I couldn't for the life of me figure out your code because I didn't realize you left out a comma. Eventually I found another sorce that looked similar to yours and realized why yours wasn't making since. Moreover, your answer didn't really answer my question or give me enough information to go look it up. I eventually found a solution to my issue and got the code working a different way.